# What are these tab icons in Chrome? I didn't specify either

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-tabs

Both pages are identical .php files except for different `<h1>` text.  But when displayed through forwarding one looks like this:

[image]

the other looks like

[image: B].

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, it's a favicon, set by the website. Each website can specify what icon to show. If the website doesn't have a favicon, the default is the page icon (the second image you've shown).

For example, notice the top of this website shows the SuperUser icon

[image]

Why does it show when you specify an `<h1>` tag? My guess is there is a coding/syntax issue on the page.

Check both pages to see if they link to a favicon... Syntax similar to
      `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">`

Now, if you don't have the code above, but still have a favicon in your root folder, then I believe the browser may display it regardless of code.